# How can i create "lo datatypes" in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

Can anybody help me to create the table with "lo datatypes".

```
CREATE TABLE image (title TEXT, img lo);
ERROR:  type "lo" does not exist
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE image (title TEXT, img lo);
                                        ^
```

i am not sure why type "lo" doesn't exits in PostgreSQL or shall i create column img with datatype **bytea**???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to create the `lo` extension that provides the data type of the same name:

```
CREATE EXTENSION lo;
```